# Is X vulnerable to Y bug?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

As of today, 90% of the questions asked are:

> "Is **[insert favorite device/application]** vulnerable to Shellshock?"

Is this question really on topic?  I understand if the question is related to how to patch/fix or how to determine if a system is vulnerable.  But I feel that asking about the vulnerability of a specific application to a specific bug is outside the realm of this stackexchange.

Is there any better way to handle these types of questions?  Is it appropriate to flag these as off topic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are not off topic as such - the best thing to do, and what usually happens with these 'bandwagon' questions, is to flag as duplicate, and we'll close 'em as dupes. The general answer usually works for all these specific ones.

Comment: This makes sense.  Hopefully things will soon die down a bit.

Comment: What is the canonical answer for the shown shellshock example?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is beyond a bandwagon question. This site is potentially a great resource but ill designed to treat it as such because of its individual question focus thus the is X to Y nature of the questions.  I am impressed by the update to the Tag which include the CVEs and suggest we consider placing other references in that tag to consolidate information and squelch the noise.  When appropriate point questioners to the Tag.